# How to get my blog reviewed by professionals?

Tags: blog, reviews

(I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask)

I have a blog where I write about technology and cybersecurity. I would like to have professionals from the field to review and evaluate my posts and give their opinions.

Any given direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is unlikely that anyone is going to review what to them must be a random blog without some kind of reward or compensation. Providing qualified and meaningful feedback on someone's writing is a lot of work, and I don't see why anyone would do that hard and time consuming job for free.

Therefore, in my opinion, you have two options:

1. You can pay an editor with a background in your field to provide feedback.
2. If your blog is successful and becomes a well-known ressource in your field, other professionals will note it and review it.

---

*Edit.*

*Based on your comment, I must assume the question you want to ask is:*

"**Where can I find an editor with a background in technology and cybersecurity?**"

*The answer to that question would be:*

There are several ways to find an editor. I'll sort them by most recommended:

1. Contact writers in your field and ask them who edited their work, what their experiences where, and who they would recommend.
2. Peruse business directories such as:

   a. https://www.the-efa.org/hiring/
   b. https://aceseditors.org/resources/for-hire
   c. https://naiwe.com/
   d. https://www.pensite.org/
   e. http://www.editorsforum.org/
   f. https://www.edsguild.org/for-clients/
   g. https://www.bookeditorsalliance.com/
   h. https://www.independenteditorsgroup.com/
   and others.
3. Use terms like "editor cybersecurity" in your search engine of choice.

Comment: Indeed 'professionals' come with cost, but my question is where to find them.

Comment: Professionals from the field have the necessary knowledge on the topics I write on, I don't see how any editor has the ability to evaluate the content without thorough research.

Comment: without getting into spiral discussion, I have to tell you that your comments brought new perspective to me on how professionals could have completely different opinions just based on their geographic locations.